# Piping email to a program & preventing rapid-fire spam submissions

Tags: php, security, email, cpanel, spam

I'm working on a site where, ideally, anyone will be able to email a specified address and attach a photo to their message (e.g. from an iPhone). This address will be set to pipe the email to a PHP script, which will then process this photo store it on our server.

I can see this system being pretty easy to abuse: someone sets up a page on their own server to repeatedly spam the address with photos, clogging up our storage space and server resources. Anyone have a suggestion on how to minimize this risk?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A few options, off of the top of my head. I'd use a combination, though:

1. Use a registration system (guarded with a CAPTCHA) so that only registered users can use the service; give each user their own secret email address, and only accept emails from their registered address. (Yes, their address can be spoofed, but it's at least some protection against casual abusers)
2. Require the user put a secret code in the subject line so that even if their `from` address is spoofed by an attacker, they'd also need to know the code or else the message is rejected
3. Set up per-account limiting
4. Limit the photo size so someone doesn't try to upload a 100 MB photo repeatedly

Comment: Well, that's what I get for skimming.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a fool proof method here. However you can treat this process like a user registration process. Once someone sends an email to you, you store the email in a temp storage, send an auto generated message back to the originating email address, asking them to click on a unique link to confirm or replying to that email with some special text.

Comment: I've thought about doing this, and the problem with any kind of registration based solely on email doesn't seem plausible- the user could register an email address, and then once it's been accepted by the system, spoof that address to send a barrage of spam.

I could do the temp storage suggestion like you said, but I also want to try to avoid the possibility of spammers using a script to send from different emails (i.e. foo1@gmail.com then foo2@gmail.com)

Comment: I think the best possibility is:

1. Send users to a shortened web address
2. Have a form with a captcha and a text box to capture their email
3. Display a one-time-use email address that they can send the photo to

Thanks everyone for helping me think through this one.